# How can I add two transition transforms but one after one?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I want to add 2 transition transforms

But I want to start the second transform after the end of the first transform

the element should go to a point slowly and after that it should go to another point

```
transform: translate(0%, 300%), translate(15%, -136%);
```

Comment: That wouldn't be possible with `transition` if both the transforms are set on the same element. You could do with `animation` but animations are different from `transition` and would make the reverse effect (say on hover-out, difficult to achieve).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will search about the ability of using animation instead of transition

Comment: If you want, I can give a solution here :)

Comment: Thanks for your help :), I'm going to learn this technique before using it, and I may use jquery animate with css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this with just a single element using `transition` because when you put more than one translate within the transform, the transform property on the whole is transitioned and not one by one.

**With pure CSS transition using an extra wrapper element:**

If you add an extra wrapper element around the actual element and put one of the transforms on the wrapper element you could achieve the effect that you are looking for. It would also produce the exact reverse effect on the hover out (hover the body and hover out in the below snippet).

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all 1s 1s;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  transition: all 1s;
}
body:hover .content {
  transform: translate(15%, -136%);
  transition: all 1s 1s;
}
body:hover > .wrapper {
  transform: translate(0%, 300%);
  transition: all 1s;
}
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='content'>Some text</div>
</div>
```

**Transition with a bit of JS/jQuery without any extra elements:**

If you add an extra wrapper element around the actual element and put one of the transforms on the wrapper element you could achieve the effect that you are looking for. It would also produce the exact reverse effect on the hover out (hover the body and hover out in the below snippet).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isHover; /* variable to track state */
  $('body').hover(function() {
    isHover = !isHover; /* invert the state */
    $('.content').css('transform', 'translate(0%, 300%)');
  }, function() {
    isHover = !isHover; /* invert the state */
    $('.content').css('transform', 'translate(0%, 300%)');
  });
  $('.content').on('transitionend', function() {
    if (isHover) {
      $('.content').css('transform', 'translate(0%, 300%) translate(15%, -136%)');
    } else {
      $('.content').css('transform', 'none');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  transition: all 1s;
}
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='content'>Some text</div>
```

---

**With animation and no extra element:**

Using animations this can be done using a single element but the reverse effect is tough to achieve. We would have to write extra code for this and even then it will be complex.

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
body:hover > .content {
  animation: move 1s forwards;
}
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0%, 300%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0%, 300%) translate(15%, -136%);
  }
}
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>Some text</div>
```

**Animations with reverse effect:**

Below is a snippet which produces the reverse effect also using CSS animations. But as you can see it is a bit complex. We can do this using a single animation also but it would become more complex.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').hover(function() {
    $('.content').css('transform', 'none');
    $('.content').removeClass('hover-out').addClass('hover-in');
  }, function() {
    $('.content').css('transform', 'translate(0%, 300%) translate(15%, -136%)'); /* as soon as an animation is removed, the element would snap back to original state, to avoid that we have to add final state via inline style */
    $('.content').removeClass('hover-in').addClass('hover-out');
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.hover-in {
  animation: hover-in 1s forwards;
}
.hover-out {
  animation: hover-out 1s forwards;
}
@keyframes hover-in {
  0% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0%, 300%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0%, 300%) translate(15%, -136%);
  }
}
@keyframes hover-out {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0%, 300%) translate(15%, -136%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0%, 300%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: none;
  }
}
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='content'>Some text</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm going to check these snippets, thanks for your time

Comment: You're welcome @Egyptian. I didn't know you were fine with using jQuery. If you can do that then this can be done using `transition` with just a single element also. I have added a sample for this also into my answer. Check if it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks :), Every thing working fine now, Thanks for every character you wrote